# How to schedule and automate python script

Tags: python

I'm rather green in python development but learning nevertheless.
I've written some python codes but they are mostly one-off use and to be run at command line. I still have no idea how to automate and schedule my codes. Lets say I have:

1. written a python script that pulls some CSV data from API and saves it in `/tmp`.
2. written another script to ingest the csv data and transform it into XML per line.

Each time I want to do this, I find myself doing:

```
$ python getdata.py 
$ python converttoxml.py
```

In shell, I think one can write a wrapper script and cron it. Right? If so, how is this done in the world of python? Bear in mind we have to include all python `libraries/` modules used, too.

P.S. developing in Linux environment using PyCharm.

Comment: Why do you need a wrapper to cron the two commands? You could just cron `python getdata.py ; python converttoxml.py` or put the two commands in a bash script that the cron job executes.

Answer (score 1):

Login to cron using `crontab -e`

Scroll to bottom at add a line following the following format:
`m h  dom mon dow   command`  which is minutes, hours, day of month, day of week, command

So if you want to run your command on the hour every hour you would have

```
* /1 * * * * python path/to/file/getdata.py
```

whereas if you want it to run at 12 only then you would have

```
* 12 * * * * python path/to/file/getdata.py
```

Comment: Uhh - format is m hour dayofmonth month.. your example you put */1 without a space? or is that just a formatting issue?

Comment: I would go a step further and write a bash script around it: this allows you in the bash script to do things like activate the virtualenv (which people should be using) etc before calling the script.

Comment: @Jmons It was a formatting issue.  There is meant to be a space but it kept getting changed to a bullet

Comment: I've just modified your answer to use a code block rather then a block quote and put the space back in ;) Hope that helps (once peer reviewed).

Answer (score 0):

Python files could be treated as executables. You just need to give them executing permissions with `chmod +x my_file.py` and tell the bash which interpreter should be used to parse the file by adding `#!/usr/bin/python` as the 1st line of the code file.

Once you've done the two things, you could just run your file using `./my_file.py` and the python script should be executed.

From this point on, it's just like any ordinary program and could be used in cron/systemd/whatever other use you need. Once you have a working Python script, it should be treated no differently than any other executable on your system - in this regard, there's no "Python World".

As far as extra modules are concerned - this shouldn't be an issue as Python will still use the same way to resolve library location. It might be necessary to update $PYTHON_PATH to add a library path - but if the library is installed correctly it shouldn't be an issue while for libraries contained within your local directory (only in the case Python fails to find them) you could add:
`sys.path.apped(os.path.dirname(__file__))` to the beginning of your script.